# How to redirect to youtube app through link from Android app?

Tags: android, redirect, youtube, deep-linking, autolink

In my UI, i have a textview to shows list content. I have auto link and app chooser dialog enabled for that textview. In case of youtube link as content (like https://youtu.be/x), upon selecting youtube app from the app chooser dialog, youtube app opens with an error screen (error code 400).
I am not sure why its happening. I have provided my code below.

```
public static void getAppChooserDialog(Context context, String url){
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> sharePackages = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createViewIntent(url),0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = createViewIntent(url);
                if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName()) &&
                        !sharePackages.contains(info.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                    if (targetedShare != null) {
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        sharePackages.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    }
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            if(!targetedShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),
                        context.getString(R.string.complete_action_using));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
    }

private Intent createViewIntent(String url){
       Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            shareIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            return shareIntent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube app doesn't support intent with the normal url (no idea why).
For an url `https://youtu.be/videoId` you need to share `vnd:youtube:videoId`